# How do I make the edges transparent over a SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter

If you can see the edges of the container with the chart are not transparent over the `FlexibleSpace` of the `AppBar` and looks weird. Right now i have a `Scaffold` and then i put the background of the theme, I've also tried to let it transparent but it doesn't work at all

[image: Screenshot]

```
      Widget pageOne() {
        return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Column(children: [Expanded(child: LineChartWidget())]),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
      )),
    );
    }

     Widget pageTwo() {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Column(children: [Expanded(child: BarChartWidget())]),
      ),
    );
      }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = PageController();
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    final appbarHeight = 200.0;
    final statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      drawer: drawer(),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 10,
            title: TitleWidget(25),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CoinView()));
                  }),
            ],
            expandedHeight: 300,
            floating: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight + 50),
                  child: Column(children: [BalanceWidget(), CoinWidget()])),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
                  height: height - 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: PageView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          pageOne(),
                          pageTwo(),
                          pageTwo(),
                          pageTwo()
                        ],
                      )),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                        child: SmoothPageIndicator(
                          controller: controller,
                          count: 4,
                          effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                              dotHeight: 5,
                              dotWidth: 15,
                              expansionFactor: 3,
                              activeDotColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that SliverAppBar is not below your SliverList, but it is just in top of it.

This means that there is no overlap in those two slivers, and that is why it looks like the bottom is clipping the SliverAppBar when it is actually the SliverAppBar contracting.

If you want the effect of the SliverList going over the flexible space, you can use a Stack. You put the contents of the SliverAppBar in the background, and then you place the CustomScrollView on top of it.

Don't forget to add an empty container with a height of 300 in the CustomScrollView's SliverAppBar to work as a "window" to the contents that are now in the background.

I hope you can work with this and solve your problem!